# ArcGIS Modelbuilder Warning empty output generated to Halt process?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, warning-000117

Is there a simple way of making ArcGIS stop if the following message comes up after "copy rows" have finished (see picture); [image]

> Executing (Copy Rows (4)): CopyRows QueryTableB_cx
>   C:\Users\fmromss\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\QueryTable_CopyRows2_cx
>   Start Time: Mon Apr 25 12:40:25 2016 WARNING 000117: **Warning empty output generated.** Succeeded at Mon Apr 25 12:40:25 2016 (Elapsed
>   Time: 0,38 seconds)

It would be quite neat if It did not export it to excel if theres not any actual data.

Bear in mind this is just a small part of the model hence I dont want the entire model to stop, just this process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be:

- Use [Get Count](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) tool on query result table and assign result of tool to a variable
- Then, use [if-then-else Branching](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//002w00000022000000) logic to check if variable is greater than 1 or not

Comment: The "get count" tool seems to do the trick by itself! Thanks man